# ERROR: input-utils-1.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed in arago project in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, makefile, sdk, arago

```
yocto@ilx:~/tisdk/build$ MACHINE=am335x-evm bitbake arago-core-tisdk-image

I am building sdk.

Not able to resolve this errors:

ERROR: input-utils-1.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: input-utils-1.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile
```

It says ERROR: input-utils-1.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed .

I found some solutions from web and tried, but it gave me same error as figure above.

Does anybody have an idea for this?